# How I put triangle to bottom border which have relative parents

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

[image]

I want to see that centered triangle in border. So, i have a problem because parent component is relative. When I remove the relative, i can't put triangle to the center. I added our code to codesandbox. Can you help me?

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-kepler-y33rl?file=/src/StepperView.tsx

Comment: An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed). So, you need that parent element to be relative in this case.

Comment: If you add `left: 50%` and set `bottom: -10px` to `:after`, and remove `overflow-x: auto` and `overflow-y: hidden` from the `wrapper`, you'll see the arrow displaying centered in bottom border.

Comment: thank you, but i want to scroll also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok... that is a little bit tricky, you cannot make elements pop out if there is a wrapper cutting everything off. try with something like this:

[image: Edit new-sky-ctme4]